# @font-face not working for fonts with subfolder

Tags: html, css, fonts, shopify, liquid

I currently have a structure as below:

```
stylesheet.css
fonts/webfont-1.woff
```

When using @font-face in the stylesheet.css,

```
src: url('fonts/webfont-1.woff');
```

does not load the font.

When I move the webfont-1.woff over to the same folder as stylesheet.css however, and change the @font-face reference in the stylesheet.css to:

```
src: url(webfont-1.woff');
```

The font works completely fine. I am doing this through the Shopify liquid platform so I'm not sure if that affects anything, but help would be greatly appreciated. I'd like the fonts to be in a subfolder for organization, but it doesn't load when I try to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with an absolute path with adding a slash '/' in front 'fonts' folder name ?
like this --> `src: url('/fonts/webfont-1.woff');`

Comment: Hi, I did try that but the font still doesn't load when in a subfolder

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the limitation comes from Shopify. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, you can't have a fonts folder in Shopify. You will have to store the files in the assets folder.